# lagrange's multipliers in fmincon

Tags: matlab

I am using 'fmincon' for an optimization problem to minimize the least square error. I have one lower bound constraint. When I analyze the  output structure of fmincon, I can see multiple lambda values for the constraint. I read that Matlab generates an approximate set of Lagrange multipliers and packages them to the output structure. But how would I know the optimum lambda for the problem? For example I have used 'Lasso' before and it gives the index of the lambda value (from the set of all lambda values) which causes minimum deviation of expected model from fitted model. 
Can someone please help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I think we might need some more details and clarification before an answer may be posted here.

Comment: `fmincon` is an interface to multiple optimization algorithms. First, find out what kind of algorithm is used in your case and if this is a sensible choice. Look for alternatives and compare them. Choose your algortithm actively, dont rely on the default algorithm. Dont use `fmincon` for least squares optimization, try `lsqnonlin`. In least squares problems, levenberg-marquardt performs great. A lower bound constraint may be removed using a transform in the parameter space.